# Show that the set of complex numbers $z$ with $|z|=1$ is not a group under the operation $*$ denoted by $z_1 * z_2 = |z_1|\times z_2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

> Show that the set of complex numbers $z$ with $|z|=1$ is not a group under the operation $*$ denoted by $z_1 * z_2 = |z_1|\times z_2.$

By solving this I found many left identity elements and couldn't find an unique right identitiy. But can't find a particular identity element. Is it enough to say that the set is not a group ?

Also please tell me 
If a set is satisfying left axioms, but not satisfying right axioms, then we will call the set a group or not ?
How many identity element can be in a group ?

Comment: There is more than one set of axioms for group theory. Your talk of "left axioms" implies that you're using a less common one than average. Please would you let us know, too, how you got your current results. You could be closer than you think!

Comment: @Shaun sorry sir, but I can't find my answers there. I can't understand what that is written in that post, most of them are in codings.

Comment: My link above is to a meta site question on how to use $\LaTeX$ to format mathematics on the main site.

Comment: @Shaun please see this e*z=|e|z, here the identity element e can be any member of the set. But if z*e=|z|e , then identity element can be only z itself. In first case the identity element is left identity and in second case is right identity.

Comment: The identity element is unique in every group. Suppose $e, e'$ are identities. Then $e=ee'$ since $e'$ is an identity, but now $ee'=e'$ since $e$ is an identity; hence $e=e'$.

Comment: @Shaun I know that identity element is unique for every member in a group. But, my question is "Is there only a single identity element in a group or more than one identity element exist?"

Comment: [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370124/show-that-the-set-of-complex-numbers-z-with-z-1-is-not-a-group-under-the-opera?noredirect=1#comment6935042_3370124) proves that identities are unique, which is to say that there is only one such element.

Comment: @Shaun thanks. :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lvert z\rvert=1$ for all $z$ in your set, we have $z_1\ast z_2=z_2$ for all $z_1, z_2$ in the set. This violates the [Latin square property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_has_Latin_Square_Property) of group multiplication. Hence it is not a group.

---

[Semigroup theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) might be of interest to you.